# In RabbitMQ how to consume multiple message or read all messages in a queue or all messages in exchange using specific key?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to consume multiple messages from specific queue or a specific exchange with a given key.

so the scenario is as follow:

Publisher publish message 1 over queue 1
Publisher publish message 2 over queue 1
Publisher publish message 3 over queue 1
Publisher publish message 4 over queue 2
Publisher publish message 5 over queue 2
..
Consumer consume messages from queue 1
get [message 1, message 2, message 3] all at once and handle them in one call back

```
listen_to(queue_name , num_of_msg_to_fetch or all, function(messages){
//do some stuff with the returned list
});
```

the messages are not coming at the same time, it is like events and i want to collect them in a queue, package them and send them to a third party.

I also read this post:

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Consuming-multiple-messages-at-a-time-td27195.html

Thanks

Comment: I do not think this is a great use case, you would have to know how many messages you are expecting in order to wait until they have all been read before handling them

Comment: I want to read whatever in the queue, up to max no. of messages. so the code will be like this: while(queue_has_messages || max_num_of_msgs == 100){ queue.consume; max_num_of_msgs++;  }

Comment: again I am not understanding the use case. You have just what you want to do, but I feel that reanalyzing this could help come up with a better solution than what you have just said.  Messages are atomic so it is better if they can be handled one by one.  If not perhaps queues are not your best solution.

Comment: If my application was going to handle the messages by itself, I would agree with you. But I aggeragate and package multiple messages, then send them to a remote machine, this machine itself -for now- can't consume messages directly. That's why I consume and pack multiple messages for it.

Comment: It looks like a very custom implementation with moving time-based windows (producer-side at least). Nothing that's trivially achievable with RMQ, as it's APIs are bound to a single-message flows that are invoked over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't consume directly from the queue as queues follow round robin algorithm(an AMQP mandate)
Use shovel to transfer the queue contents to a fanout exchange and consume messages right from this exchange. You get all messages across all connected consumers. :)

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the OP's question. They want to be able to read more than one message at a time to be able to perform a batch operation on such multiple messages, instead of reading them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume multiple messages from specific queue, you can try as below.

```
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false,false, null);
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel){
   @Override
   public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                       Envelope envelope,
                                       AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                       byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                
                    String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                    logger.info("Recieved Message --> " + message);
                
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to conceptually separate domain-message from RMQ-message. As a producer you'd then bundle multiple domain messages into a single RMQ-message and `.produce()` it to RMQ. Remember this kind of design introduces timeouts and latencies due to the existence of a window (you might take some impression from Kafka that does bundling to optimize I/O at the cost of latency).

As a consumer then, you'd have a consumer, with typical `.handleDelivery` implementation that would transform the received body for the processing: `byte[] -> Set[DomainMessage] -> your listener`.