# pika, rabbitmq - get all messages from the queue without consuming them

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, pika, python-pika

Using the `pika` client, I want to display all the messages currently in the queue, without consuming them. Just to know how busy is the queue and display the jobs.

So far, I can only read one message as it arrives:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue='queue1', durable=True)
channel.basic_consume(on_message, queue='queue1')
channel.start_consuming()

def on_message(channel, method, properties, message):
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    print("Message: %s", message)
```

How can I read the whole queue?

Comment: Check this out!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647268/in-rabbitmq-how-to-consume-multiple-message-or-read-all-messages-in-a-queue-or-a

Answer (score 1):

To read messages "without consuming them", don't acknowledge delivery of the message. In your case above, get rid of

```
channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

or set `auto_ack` to `False`:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(body)
   
channel.basic_consume(queue='your_queue', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)
```

The messages will be read and marked as unacked in rabbitMQ but will still be available in the queue.

Comment: `auto_ack` doesn't seem to work for me (using `pika.BlockingConnection`):
`TypeError: basic_consume() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_ack'`